# How to solve $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} f(3x) + \cos x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functional-equations

Using the Banach fixed-point theorem, I can prove that there exists exactly one continuous function $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(3x)+\cos x.$$

I currently don't know how to solve this $f$ precisely. My attempt is similar to Picard iteration. Define
$$Tf = \frac{1}{2}f(3x)+\cos x.$$
Let $f_0 = 2$, and $f_{n+1} = Tf_n$. I can calculate that
$$f_n = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cos 3^{n-1}x + \cdots + \frac{1}{2}\cos 3x+ \cos x + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$
But what is the limit of this $f_n$? Thank you for any solutions or hints to this problem.

Edit: Adding the plots of $f_1,f_3$ and $f_5$ in the interval $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$, JL

[image]

Comment: The limit is $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(3^n x)}{2^n}$, but I doubt that there is a more explicit form. It reminds me of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: Agree with @MartinR. Adding $f_8$ to the plot would make it too messy. The sequence converges w.r.t. the sup-norm for sure, but the limit is a bit unwieldy.

Comment: I see！Thank you for your relpy！

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714880/functional-equations-with-nowhere-differentiable-solutions/1722171#1722171